# Issue with connecting image target database from vuforia engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have 2 separate projects in Unity which require Vuforia Image targets. I have already created the Image target database in Vuforia developer platform and added my image to it. However, it shows up in only one of the projects. Can I use the same vuforia profile for multiple unity projects or do I need a new profile? What could be the issue, any guidance?

I tried to create another database as well, but none of them show up and I checked the login and unity version control it all matches for both projects.